Google Meet REST API Permission denied on resource Space (or it might not exist) error
I have just configured everything in google cloud console, i am using service account as auth method and i download key file as json. But i am getting this error
"Call failed with message: { "message": "Permission denied on resource Space (or it might not exist)", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [] }"
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Google\ApiCore\ApiException;
use Google\ApiCore\ValidationException;
use Google\Apps\Meet\V2\Client\SpacesServiceClient;
use Google\Apps\Meet\V2\CreateSpaceRequest;
use Google\Apps\Meet\V2\Space;

class YourControllerName extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $spacesServiceClient  = new SpacesServiceClient([
            'credentials' => storage_path('app\google-calendar\credentials.json')
        ]);

        $request = new CreateSpaceRequest();

        try {
            $response = $spacesServiceClient->createSpace($request);
            printf('Response data: %s' . PHP_EOL, $response->serializeToJsonString());
        } catch (ApiException $ex) {
            printf('Call failed with message: %s' . PHP_EOL, $ex->getMessage());
        }
    


How did you grant the service account access?

@LindaLawton-DaImTo
1- i went to google cloud console
2- searched for google meets rest api
3- clicked and enabled it
4- the from the left menu i went crendantials page
5- clicked create crendantials button on the top select service account
6- for account access i selected owner role since i couldn't find anything spesific to google meets api
7- then finished and install key as json

Yes but the google meets space not everyone has access to this new space that was created do they they need to be invited to it

You mean i need to add invitation to my code ?

A service account is not you.  Think of it as a dummy user.  It can only access what it has access to.   I cant access that Space unless you grant me access to it. You need to grant the service account access as well.

how ? is there role or permission to grant service account so he can access created spaces ? There is bunch of roles and permissions but i can't see anything related to google meets ?

How did you create the sapce?  was it via google workspace?

I just tried with a standard gmail space and i cant invite the service account.

i think i need domain wide delegation for accessing things like calender, meets from service account

You can only configure that from a Google Workspace domain

i created workspace account with domain and added service account to domain wide delegation with specified oauth scopes still i am getting same error

Can I see the code you used to perform deligation

Same as my post i didn't change anything is there something specific needed in code for domain wide delegation i didn't heard about that

I think you should ask over on the google-cloud-php they may be able to help you there.  I have never heard of delegating to workspace with the google cloud library.

problem fixed thank you so much
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/7257

you should anwser your own question.

after setting up domain wide delegation and other related configurations on google cloud console this code worked for me
public function index(){
     $credentials = (new ServiceAccountCredentials(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created']
         ,base_path("key.json"),
         'test@test.com'
     ));
    // Create a client.
    $spacesServiceClient = new SpacesServiceClient(['credentials' => $credentials]);

    // Prepare the request message.
    $request = new CreateSpaceRequest();

    // Call the API and handle any network failures.
    try {
        /** @var Space $response */
        $response = $spacesServiceClient->createSpace($request);
        printf('Response data: %s' . PHP_EOL, $response->serializeToJsonString());
    } catch (ApiException $ex) {
        printf('Call failed with message: %s' . PHP_EOL, $ex->getMessage());
    }
}


What are "Other related configurations on Google Cloud Console"? Can you share more info?
